# How many Tokens in below F#

Tags: f#, token

```
 let sub4  a b c d =
     a-b-c-d;


 printfn"%d" sub4;
```

I'm thinking there are 14 tokens in first one and 5 tokens in second one.
Another confusion is "sub4","a" here is identifier ,"printfn" is keyword, and "%d" is literal ,right?

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the counting will somewhat depend on what you mean by a "token". 
The most over-engineered solution to this answer is to use [the F# compiler itself](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/tokenizer.html) to parse the source code and report what it parses.

The following invokes the F# parser and reports the tokens that the parser sees when it looks at your code:

```
#r "FSharp.Compiler.Service.dll"
open FSharp.Compiler.SourceCodeServices

let sourceTok = FSharpSourceTokenizer([], Some "C:\\test.fsx")
let tokenizer = sourceTok.CreateLineTokenizer("""let sub4 a b c d =
     a-b-c-d;

 printfn"%d" sub4;""")

Seq.unfold (fun state -> 
  let res, state = tokenizer.ScanToken(state)
  res |> Option.map (fun res -> res, state) ) FSharpTokenizerLexState.Initial
|> Seq.filter (fun t -> t.TokenName <> "WHITESPACE")
|> Seq.iter (fun t -> printf "%s, " t.TokenName)
```

The tokenizer counts whitespace as tokens, but I assume you want to skip over those, so I added a bit of code to filter those out. The result is (formatted to match the source code lines):

> LET, IDENT, IDENT, IDENT, IDENT, IDENT, EQUALS
>   IDENT, MINUS, IDENT, MINUS, IDENT, MINUS, IDENT, SEMICOLON
>
> IDENT, STRING_TEXT, STRING_TEXT, STRING_TEXT, STRING, IDENT, SEMICOLON

This should give you a good idea about what the F# compiler considers as a token.

- The F# parser treats semicolon as a token - it's a valid token in the language, because it's used to separate expressions, but you may or may not want to count it.
- The F# tokenizer is a bit confused by the string `"%d"` and parses this as a couple of separate STRING_TEXT and STRING tokens - but this is just a technical aspect of the tokenizer, so I would count all of those as just a single token.

Comment: Thank  you for helping! If I understand right, a b c d is four inputs for function sub4. And we consider  a b c d as one identifier token?

Comment: In `let sub4 a b c d`, the `let` is a keyword and `sub4` is the name of a function you are defining. `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are four parameters the function. Each of those is a separate identifier (and a separate token).